# Return the number of rows with MySQLi

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to return the number of rows found in my database. Using a php mvc framework for the first time so quite new to me (as is php).

My query works fine and the data is displayed as expected within the table.

I'm not quite sure where I should put the code? I have been looking at `mysqli_num_rows()`, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` and `PDOStatement::rowCount()` - which of these should I use if any?

I would just like to display

> We have found x number of records!

My code so far;

### Model

```
public function categoryView()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 
    id, 
    title,
    FROM book 
    WHERE status != 'Archive' AND category='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");

    $sth->execute();

    $all_books = array();

    foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $book) {

        $all_books[$book->id] = new stdClass();
        $all_books[$book->id]->id = $book->id;
        $all_books[$book->id]->title = $book->title; 
    }
    return $all_books;
}
```

### View

```
foreach ($this->books as $book) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$book->id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$book->title.'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You can use -->  $sth->execute();   $result =  $sth->$sth->fetchAll();  $countRows = $sth->num_rows;   This is faster than normal count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to correct part of your code. First, `mysql()` functions are long depreciated and should not be in use, especially `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Instead, you need to [do a little bit of reading about PDO bound values](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). I'm guessing from the layout and default values I see in your provided code you've probably built your system on PHP-Mini (Which is PDO) although considering I see `$sth->execute();` it's definitely PDO, so your query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title "
     . "FROM book "
     . "WHERE status != 'Archive' AND category = :cat "
     . "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':cat', $_GET['category']);
$sth->execute();
```

Then, to return the count, because `PDO::rowCount()` behaviour is unpredictable with select statements, use

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return count($result);
```

While the answer you accepted does indeed work, I would recommend making the above changes (at least to the query) for security and best practice reasons.

Comment: @johnny_s it also happens to be the worst possible way to do this.

Comment: "because PDO::rowCount() behaviour is unpredictable with select statements" <-- can you explain how it's unpredictable? Because it's not.

Comment: @ircmaxell `If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.` Straight from the PHP.net manual. It might work with most MySQL installs but some of us also use MSSQL, Postgre and Oracle etc. Doesn't work there so well.

Comment: @tereško Worse than using depreciated `Mysql()` functions and dropping unsanitised variables directly into a query?

Comment: @iamgory where do I add the code you have provided in the Model/View? I thought it was working but on further testing it's not. I receive an Notice: Undefined variable: result in my view on line 47 (this line is Found <?php echo count($result); ?> records)

Comment: If you're using PHP mini, you'd want to call it from the controller (really, presenter) by `$var = $model_name->modelFunction();` then echoing $var

Comment: @iamgory yes, however this question is in the context of MySQL. Therefore suggesting not to use it is not good.

Comment: @ircmaxell Without phpinfo() you don't know what versions of MySQL/PHP he's running, or what versions the codebase will be deployed on. You should never assume. Also, I said "most" MysQL, not all - I've seen it perform incorrectly before on MySQL/PHP installs.

Answer (score 0):

short cut would be in your view do something like this: echo count($this->books);

another way would be to push the value into your array in your controller:
return array('books' => $all_books, 'row_count' => count($all_books));